# How would you read /var/logs/something.log and only send what's new?

Tags: raspbian

I am deploying a raspberry pi in a remote location with a stable internet connection. The pi will run 24/7 and has a few services which output their logs to `/var/logs/A.log`, `/var/logs/B.log` etc.

I am planning to write a python script that will be run by crontab every 15 minutes. This script will read through the logs and **only send what's not been sent before**.

How should I do this? What would your recommendations be?

*Due to the fact that the raspberry pi runs on a sd card, I don't know whether it would be that good an idea to use a database as I want to limit the number of writes to the SD card which has a higher rate of failure.*

Comment: You shouldn't do this. First, you should check if someone else had not done it before. Start with [Syslog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog) (from year 1980) and its derivatives, or with [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) / Elastic Stack if you are into more modern things.

Comment: To add to what @techraf said there are several good remote logservices including loggly, papertrail etc. You can get a more complete list here http://alternativeto.net/software/loggly/

Answer (score 1):

Well, this:

```
stat -c "%s" /var/log/syslog
```

Will give you just the current size of the file in bytes.  And this:

```
tail -c $((A-B)) /var/log/syslog
```

With the shell will give you the last A - B bytes, presuming "A" and "B" are actual numbers (or variables representing integers).

That's not python, but that's the idea.